# Making HTML table from MYSQL database columns

Tags: html, mysql, sql, html-table

I am learning something new in MySQL. I would like to import some data from outer database into my local HTML table. But the database I want to use for import it is such a mess. I have to really select what I want to import.

db > database1

1st table with data > "trr_post" 
2nd table with data > "trr_metapost"

1st table column with data > "post_title"
2nd table column with data > "post_value"

I would like to make an HTML table where data will set in a row. For example in a first row first column will contain data from "post_title", but not all data (I would like to select them by ID). Same row, but second column will contain data from "post_value" table (selected by ID) and so on ...

In a short way, I would like to choose which data from database will be shown in my HTML table. And I know I can't use simple :

```
SELECT post_value
FROM trr_metapost
WHERE column_id = "20"
```

Comment: typically, when making html and using MySQL, you would be using another programming language, like PHP or python. If you can't generate a SQL query that will return what you want, you can always check the output in whatever language you are using to generate the HTML and fix things there.

Comment: Please clarify, table1 has a column name "post_title" and table2 has column name"post_value". you simply want something like |id|post_title|post_value| and the data selection will be done by some ids which is present in both the tables right??

Comment: you are definitely right #Ayush choubey I want something like that, clearly make the selection of column I want to use in my HTML table. And I know I can use PHP, maybe I will. Because actually I am using some Joomla module, which uses SQL Query to give these commands.